# facebook login does not give me user email upon successful response

Tags: angularjs, facebook

My code is as shown below:

```
$scope.FBLogin = function() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        FB.api('/me?fields=first_name,email', function(response) {
                            console.log("good to see you" + JSON.stringify(response));

                    } else {
                        console.log("user cancelled login");
                    }
                });
            };
```

In the response I am only geeting user name and id . I do not get user email field. So is there anything missing in this code ?

This is the configuration that I am using

```
 $window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'id',
                autoLogAppEvents: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.10'
            });
            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Of course there is something missing, you failed to ask the user for permission to access their email.

Comment: @CBroe I have already followed all the steps (I think ) for facebook login. So can you elaborate where should I ask user for email permission?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: I cross checked in my facbook account, I have already enabled the permission for email id.

Comment: Is the email address verified?

Comment: I got the flaw in my application. In my test users, I was using the id given bydefault and it did not have v2.10 support. So I created new one with v2.10 support and then it started giving me email_id in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the flaw in my application. In my test users, I was using the email id given bydefault and it did not have v2.10 support. So I created new one with v2.10 support and then it started giving me email_id in response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this or you can also refer this below link once https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.10

```
   FB.login(function(response) {
       // handle the response
   }, {scope: 'email'});
```

Comment: No, it is not working. The response remians the same which I got for my code.